# Meteor 1.2: Xcode 7.0.1 build issue

Tags: xcode, meteor, xcode7, meteor-ios

I recently updated my Xcode to Xcode 7.0.1. My project used to compile and build for ios without issues on Xcode 6.4. Now, I'm having this error:

Cordova/CDVViewController.h file not found in the line -

```
#import <Cordova/CDVViewController.h>
```

Please let me know how to fix this.

P.S. "archiving" doesn't produce errors

Comment: I have the same issue! This was not happening before and now it is after I upgraded Xcode. Although I can build and run on the device but I cannot archive the product for submission.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here: http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cordova-cdvviewcontroller-h-file-not-found-in-xcode-7-1-beta/32232/5

From the author `shazron`

Add this line to your Build Settings -> Header Search Paths:

`"$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include"`

Don't replace the existing line that looks similar, that is still needed to be backwards compatible with Xcode 7 and Xcode 6.4.

This probably had something to do with tvOS, I reckon -- Apple had to separate the archive intermediates by platform for universal builds.

Comment: I was using Xcode 7.1. Ours is not the same issue. I was having issues only archiving to submit to app store. I could build and run on device no problem.